# tkinter ttk treeview, how to set data type

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I got a problem about data type when using ttk treeview. Firstly, I insert data to treeview by

```
treeview.insert('', 'end', values = ['1', 'tom', 50])
```

Then I try to get the selected data row in the UI by

```
sel = treeview.selection[0] 
treeview.item(sel)['values']
```

Then I got the data `row = [1, 'tom', 50]`.  the first data(1)'s data type changed from String to int. and the python list differentiates `[1]` and `['1']`, and makes problem for my later data process.  Is there a way to set the data type for all the data column to be String?  Thank you !

As someone mentioned, it is easy to fix the one data column manually. But the problem is: the operation I want to do is to insert data by a list of data_row, and then remove the selected data_row from the list later. The problem of changing the data type will not allow me to remove them from the original list.  And, the original list is obtained from some other module and so I wont be able to know the data type of each column in data row.  It would be so little efficient if I check and maintain the data type of each column myself. And if there is different list of data row, I will need to check and maintain every list.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot set the type of the data in the treeview but you can convert yourself the first value to string after retrieving it.

Comment: Actually, on the Tcl side, everything is already a string, therefore [`item`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py#L1373) returns a proper tuple of strings. Hovewer, on the Python side all the data is silently converted to a more appropriate Python object. [Literally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py#L304). So, as @j_4321 mentioned, you have to do your conversion by yourself.

Comment: @CommonSense   Thank you for explaining it. The operation I want to do is to insert data by a list of data_row, and then remove the selected data_row from the list later.  The problem of changing the data type will not allow me to remove them from the original list.  Yes,  it is only a known data type changing, I can fix it myself.  But, the original list is obtained from some other modules and so I wont be able to know the data type of each column in data row .  It would be so little efficient if I check and maintain the data type of each column myself.