# python tkinter ttk Treeview changes data

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm using ttk.Treeview to display a list of customer IDs and names from a database.  My  customer ID column is a six-character numeric string, with leading zeros (i.e. customer number 19 is "000019").

When it's displayed in the tree it looks correct.  When I get the value by clicking the entry, however, something along the way decides that "000019" is an integer, and converts it from a string, dropping the leading zeros.  This is not expected or desired, as I need "000019" for an update query.

Tree creation code (simplified, this will not run copy/paste):

```
column_names = ('customer_id', 'customer_name')

customer_tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=column_names, show='headings')
customer_tree.heading('customer_id', text="Customer ID")
customer_tree.heading('customer_name', text="Customer Name")
customer_tree.tag_bind('ttk', '<ButtonRelease-1>', get_customer_id)

customer_list = []

get_customers() # runs the queries from the db to populate customer_list[]

for i in customer_list:
        
    customer_tree.insert("", "end", values=(i[0], i[1]), tags=('ttk', 'simple'))

def get_customer_id():

    print(type(customer_tree.item(customer_tree.focus())['values'][0]))
```

Clicking an entry in the tree returns `<class 'int'>` to the console.

This is fixable:

```
def get_customer_id():
    new_customer_id = str(customer_id)

    while len(new_customer_id) < 6:
        new_customer_id = ("0" + new_customer_id)
```

I'm just wondering if there is something I can do to keep the backend transformation from happening, or if I have to live with this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: as requested, the get_customers function (dbconn is defined elsewhere and is not relevant):

```
def get_customers():
    customer_query = ("SELECT customer_id, customer_name, FROM customers ORDER BY customer_id DESC")
    dbconn.cursor.execute(customer_query)
    customer_result = dbconn.cursor.fetchone()

    while isinstance(customer_result, tuple):
        customer_list.append(customer_result)
        customer_result = dbconn.cursor.fetchone()
```

customer_id is defined in the database as varchar(6).  Again, it displays correctly in the tree as a string with the value of "000019", so I'm not worried about the query results.

Comment: You need to show us what's happening in the `get_customers` function. I think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604831/tkinter-ttk-treeview-how-to-set-data-type) has been asked around 4 years ago without answer.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543314/why-are-the-digit-values-in-the-tkinter-items-integers-and-not-strings-even-when) is a workaround from 2021. I tried it with your code sample and it works nicely. Still this is not a ttk solution.

Comment: After seeing a Youtube video from someone much smarter than I am, I have reworked my fix to:

 def customer_id():

    new_customer_id = str(customer_id).zfill(6)

This saves me a while loop; business rules tell me the customer number will be six digits with leading zeros.