# How to get all values with leading zerros from a column in Treeview in TKinter using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I added strings to a treeview value with leading zeros (like phone number).

By reading the value out of the treeview, python convert the string into a number and the leading zeros are lost. When I look in debugger at the 'item' (see code) there I see that the string already converted to number.
How can I change the code to get the value as a string.
Thanks for any help

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Treeview Example")

# build a Treeviews
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
tree["columns"] = ("name", "age", "phone")
tree.heading("#0", text="ID", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("name", text="Name", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("age", text="Age", anchor=tk.W)
tree.heading("phone", text="Phone", anchor=tk.W)
tree.insert("", tk.END, text="001", values=("Max ", "30", "0011223344"))

# read data from Treeview

child = tree.get_children()
if child:
    tree.focus(child[0])
    tree.selection_set(child[0])
                    
item = tree.item(tree.focus())

values = item["values"]
for value in values:
    print(str(value))  # wrong result: "11223344"

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604831/tkinter-ttk-treeview-how-to-set-data-type

Answer (score 0):

Using `zfill()` inbuild method to add the zeros to the string.

```
N = 2

print('0' * N + value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
If this was the problem, it'll be easy - then I can fill the string.
but the leading zeros are not at every string. I first read all data from the database by sql-command and put it int the treeview. for further editing i want to reduce data access and read the data form the treeview.
I thing the best solution is to read the data again from database.